# Select the text from the cursor to the character in vim

Tags: lua, neovim

I needed a keymapping that would allow me to jump to the nearest { and } character. I found this solution:

```
vim.keymap.set( 'n', '<S-Up>', ":call search('{', 'b')<CR>zz", { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.keymap.set( 'n', '<S-Down>', ":call search('}')<CR>zz", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

And it works fine in normal mode. However, I'd like to do something similar in visual mode, but have the keymapping select text from the cursor to the nearest { or } character. I modified the script like this:

```
vim.keymap.set({ 'n', 'v' }, '<S-Up>', ":call search('{', 'b')<CR>zz", { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.keymap.set({ 'n', 'v' }, '<S-Down>', ":call search('}')<CR>zz", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

But in visual mode, it doesn't work. I simply jump to the character as in normal mode, but nothing is selected.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `:help ]]`?